# What is the name for the type of "loose" search/filter that allows for other characters in the middle?

Tags: regex, search

*I'm not sure which community this belongs in, feel free to suggest a better one if this doesn't fit here.*

In Visual Studio Code, when searching for a file, you can `CMD/Ctrl + P` to bring up  the [Quick Open search box](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_quick-file-navigation) for finding a file by name. The search doesn't have to be the exact name and it filters as long as the search query contains the characters in that order, while being "loose" enough to ignore any characters between those.

Example:
Searching "cat" would show the following:

- bigcat.txt
- cat.txt
- candlelight.txt

In the above, all the strings contain "cat" within it, even if there are other characters between it. The regex would probably be something like `/.*c.*a.*t.*/`.

Is there a name for this type of search/filter?

Comment: It's called a `wildcard`.  Or maybe you're asking about a `regular expression`.

Comment: I think those are techniques to get that type of search. I posted the regular expression for what the code would be for that type of search. I'm looking to see what/if there is a name for this type of search. Note, in the above example, the search would be "cat", not the regex I posted, to get those results.

Answer (score 0):

**Fuzzy Filter/Search**

After looking through VS Code's GitHub issues list, I found [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99171) that mentioned it.

I also found a [node module](https://github.com/mattyork/fuzzy) that does this exact same thing.

There is also a Wikipedia entry on [Approximate String Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching), which is similar to the above.